# Invalid formula issue while applying highlighting duplicate formula in google sheet

Tags: google-sheets, count, duplicates, google-sheets-formula, conditional-formatting

I tried to simply apply the highlight duplicate cells formula in google sheet by adding conditional formating rule, but when I click on done it shows invalid formula.

[image: screenshot of invalid formula]

Answer (score 2):

use semicolon `;`

```
=COUNTIF(F:F; F1)>1
```